# Convert a 2D JavaScript array to a 1D array

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a 2D JavaScript array to a 1D array, so that each element of the 2D array will be concatenated into a single 1D array.

Here, I'm trying to convert `arrToConvert` to a 1D array.

```
var arrToConvert = [[0,0,1],[2,3,3],[4,4,5]];

console.log(get1DArray(arrToConvert)); //print the converted array

function get1DArray(2dArr){
    //concatenate each element of the input into a 1D array, and return the output
    //what would be the best way to implement this function?
}
```

Comment: `Array.join()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It looks like `Array.join()` returns a string instead of an array.

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you mean that you want the 3 sub-arrays flattened into one array? I misunderstood I think.

Comment: Isn't it simple as that ```arrToConvert.flat()```?

Comment: How would you do this if some elements are arrays and some aren't. For example how would you convert `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ['a', 'b', 'c']]` to `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c']`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
var arrToConvert = [[0,0,1],[2,3,3],[4,4,5]];
var newArr = [];


for(var i = 0; i < arrToConvert.length; i++)
{
    newArr = newArr.concat(arrToConvert[i]);
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 164):

### Use the ES6 Spread Operator

```
arr1d = [].concat(...arr2d);
```

Note that this method is only works if `arr2d` has less than about 100 000 subarrays. If your array gets larger than that you will get a `RangeError: too many function arguments`.

### For > ~100 000 rows

```
arr = [];
for (row of table) for (e of row) arr.push(e);
```

*`concat()` is too slow in this case anyway.*

### The Underscore.js way

This will recursively flatten arrays of any depth (should also work for large arrays):

```
arr1d = _.flatten(arr2d);
```

*If you only want to flatten it a single level, pass `true` as the 2nd argument.*

### A short < ES6 way

```
arr1d = [].concat.apply([], arr2d);
```

Comment: the underscore way gives me an error when I try to use it on something simple, says that it is undefince

Comment: @daddycardona underscore.js is an external library. It will be undefined till you import it. http://underscorejs.org

Comment: Just Complementing... ES2019 introduced the .flat() method in Array Prototype. You can pass "depth" paramter in flat() method to specify how deep a nested array structure should be flattened. Defaults to 1.

Answer (score 32):

Try [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var test2d = [
  ["foo", "bar"],
  ["baz", "biz"]
];
var merged = test2d.reduce(function(prev, next) {
  return prev.concat(next);
});

console.log(merged)
```

**Source**: http://jsperf.com/2-dimensional-array-merge

Answer (score 14):

How about:

```
var arrToConvert = [[0,0,1],[2,3,3],[4,4,5]];

function get1DArray(arr){
    return arr.join().split(",");
}

console.log(get1DArray(arrToConvert));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JRR4J/

Comment: What happens if the nested elements are objects rather than numbers or strings?

Comment: @MartyWallace `["0", "0", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "[object Object]"]` This is what happens.  I see your point my solution will only work with strings and numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrToConvert = [[0,0,1],[2,3,3],[4,4,5]];

var modifiedArray = arrToConvert.map(function(array){ 
    return array[0]+array[1]+array[2];
});
```

Another Example

```
var passengers = [ 
  ["Thomas", "Meeks"],
  ["Gregg", "Pollack"],
  ["Christine", "Wong"],
  ["Dan", "McGaw"]
];

var modifiedNames = passengers.map(function(convArray){
    return convArray[0]+" "+convArray[1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrToConvert = [[0, 0, 1], [2, 3, 3], [4, 4, 5]];

function get1DArray(arr){

    var result = new Array();

    for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
        for (var y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++){

        result.push(arr[x][y])

        }
    }

    return result
}


alert (get1DArray(arrToConvert))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Saturnix/ReeqQ/