# How to flatten a 2D slice into 1D slice?

Tags: go, slice, flatten

I have

```
arr := [][]int32 {{1,2,3} ,{4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}
```

and I want

```
newArr := []int32 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

In JS I can do

```
arr1d = [].concat(...arr2d);
```

as one of many simple ways like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824283/convert-a-2d-javascript-array-to-a-1d-array)

Is there in Go something like this?

Comment: What's wrong with a for loop?

Comment: nothing really but since I'm moving from JS I would like to know if there are similar ways of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As predicted by Eli Bendersky, from Go 1.22 you have [slices.Concat](https://pkg.go.dev/slices@go1.22.0#Concat)

Answer (score 4):

Go has `strings.Join` and `bytes.Join`, but no generic functionality to join/concat a slice. It's possible that [once generics are introduced into the language](https://blog.golang.org/why-generics) such functionality will be added to the standard library.

In the meantime, doing this with a loop is clear and concise enough.

```
var newArr []int32
for _, a := range arr {
  newArr = append(newArr, a...)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Go 1.18

You can't avoid a for loop, but with generics this is easily extensible to slices of any type:

```
func Flatten[T any](lists [][]T) []T {
    var res []T
    for _, list := range lists {
        res = append(res, list...)
    }
    return res
}
```

Example usage:

```
func main() {
    w := [][]string{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}
    v := Flatten(w)
    fmt.Println(v) // [a b c d e f]

    d := [][]uint64{{100, 200}, {3000, 4000}}
    e := Flatten(d)
    fmt.Println(e) // [100 200 3000 4000]
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/X81g7GYFd4n