# How do i concat an array only when it's not undefined

Tags: javascript

I need to add multiple arrays together depending on user's preference some array might appear empty, how do I make sure the array I'm about to concat is not empty

here is my failed code

```
const num1 = [12,67,100] 
const num2 = [] 
const num3 = [23,191, 58]
const num4 = [23,30]

const numbers = num1.concat(`num${Math.random() * 10}`)
```

Comment: Create a 2D array (an array of arrays) instead of trying to access variables dynamically. Also, it's unclear what you mean by selecting an based on *user's preference* when you're using `Math.random()`

Comment: You can simply add check for Array.length, if length is > 0, then only add.

Comment: Even if the array is empty it should not be an issue as `[1,2].concat([])` is same as `[1,2]`

Comment: what i mean is undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How do I create dynamic variable names inside a loop?](/q/8260156/90527)", "[Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](/q/5117127/90527)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const num1 = [12, 67, 100]
const num2 = []
const num3 = [23, 191, 58]
const num4 = [23, 30]

const check = `num${Math.random() * 10}`
const numbers = num1.concat(check && check)

console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39805778/4062197), converting to 2d array and convert it to a single flat array, seems like the preferred solution

```
const values = [ [12,67,100], [], [23,191, 58], [23,30] ]

const numbers = [].concat(...values)

console.log(`items count: ${numbers.length}`)

const randomNumbers = numbers.map(num => parseInt(num * Math.random()))
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go, easy to understand:

```
constant numbers;
int randomArray = `num${Math.random() * 10}`;

if (randomArray.length > 0)
{
    numbers = num1.concat(randomArray);
}
```