# Use spread operator over a spread operator on an 2-d array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, v8

Is there a way to use a spread operator over another spread operator?

```
const arr = [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6],[7,8,9]];
const spreadArr = [...arr];  // This works
console.log(spreadArr); // [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

But, can we somehow chain it like we can over the map, filter or other methods?

With the output to probably spread the 2d-array into a 1-d one.
And the code or syntax to be something like:

```
const doubleSpreadArr = [...(...arr)];
console.log('The expected output to be: ', doubleSpreadArr);
// The output expected to be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

***How does the spread operator exactly work in JavaScript(v8, or any other engine)?***

Comment: Use [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)?

Comment: Maybe use `.flat()` method of array?

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824283/convert-a-2d-javascript-array-to-a-1d-array

Comment: I understood the concept of flattening of multi-dimensional arrays, that can even be done using loops, but what I am trying to ask here is how does the spread operator work and what is the reason that it cannot be chained?

Comment: It's not an operator. It's part of array syntax. That's why it cannot be nested.